# Overflow in DIV by wrapping not scrollbars

Tags: html, css

Given a DIV with a fixed width, is there a way to have it use as much vertical space as it needs by wrapping the content (which is plain text)? The CSS "overflow" property provides for scrollbars (overflow:scroll) and chopping content (overflow:hidden) but that's not what I want.

Help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah. Just leave it alone. It will resize to the content vertically just fine. Your page might get a scrollbar, though.

Comment: Make sure you've removed any explicit height that you may have set, too. You will want a height of "auto," the default.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. With only "width:300px" set, the content overflows the div instead of wrapping. The DIV is in a TD, does that make a difference?

Comment: @VANJ: Uh, yeah, that can make a difference. Why don't you post a link or some code?

Comment: Yikes, there was a TD somewhere in the markup with "nowrap" set. Getting rid of that and adding "white-space:normal" to the DIV did what I wanted. Thanks!